# Confirmation instruction on other email with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two email fields in my model :email and :representative_email I want to send confirmation instructions email on :representative_email (if present or not nil) rather than :email how can I do it with efficiently. And I still want to login with my :email field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to override headers_for method for devise within mailer

```
class DeviseCustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    headers = {
      subject: subject_for(action),
      to: resource.notification_email_for(action), #I changed this line
      from: mailer_sender(devise_mapping),
      reply_to: mailer_reply_to(devise_mapping),
      template_path: template_paths,
      template_name: action
    }.merge(opts)

    @email = headers[:to]
    headers
  end
end
```

and in my user.rb

```
def notification_email_for(action)
  (self.company? && self.authorised_representative && action == :confirmation_instructions) ? self.representative_email : self.email
end
```

and in my config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer = 'DeviseCustomMailer'
```

that's it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom mailer [see how to do that](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer), and set the email you want to send to in there.
That is the cleanest solution I could think of, and in the future if you want to change anything you can change it in one place only.

Comment: yes I needed to write custom mailer but little more described in my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing, others will benefit from that.